# list is getting updated but data is updated on dom in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs

Here is my code to create a TODO list, the problem is when I add an item the list is getting updated but when I am deleting an item the list is not getting updated.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App(){

  const [item, setItem] = useState("");
  const [list, updateList] = useState([]);

  let todoList = <p>list is empty</p>
  //creating a list
  if(list.length!== 0){
    todoList =  list.map((res, index) =>{
    return <li key={index} onClick={() => deleteItem(index)}>{res}</li>;
    });
  }
  else{

    // adding an item in todo list

    todoList = <p>list is empty</p>
  }

 
  function incre(){
    let addItem = [];
    if(list){
      addItem = list;
      addItem.push(item);
    }
    else{
      addItem = item;
    }
    updateList(addItem);
    setItem("");
  }
  // deleting item from todo list
  function deleteItem(item){
    let updatedList = list;

    updatedList.splice(item, 1);
    console.log(list);
    updateList(updatedList);
  }
  // input query
  let query = (event) =>{
    const { value } = event.target;
    setItem(value);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input 
        onChange={(e) => {query(e)}}
        value={item} />
      <button onClick={incre}>
        click me
      </button>
      <p>{item}</p>
      <ul>
        {todoList}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Note `let updatedList = list` **does not** create a copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you are mutating your state. Creating a new variable and setting to your state does not create a fresh new variable. If you mutate it, you also mutate the original one. So, you should avoid doing this.

Also, `push` and `splice` methods mutate the original array. Again, you should avoid doing those methods. Instead, you can use other methods that do not mutate the original arrays.

To add you can use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```
function incre(){
  updateList(prev => [...prev, item]);
  setItem("");
}
```

To remove, you can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
function deleteItem(itemIndex){
  const updatedList = list.filter((_, index) => itemIndex !== index)
  updateList(updatedList);
}
```